# wso2 header authentication bearer

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I get an file.xml has some syntax errors whenever i tried setting a header for authentication in wso2 developer studio

```
<header name="Authentication" scope="default" value="Bearer code"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the error ?

Comment: @DilshaniS Unknown synapse configuration tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in this configuration. ESB synapse can not validate your requirement with given configurations.

```
<header name="Authentication" scope="default" value="Bearer code"/>
```

You are going to add SOAP header as you define scope as "default". In WSO2 documentation, you may find sample scenarios for adding a header [1]

```
<header xmlns:m="http://org.synapse.example" xmlns:sym="http://services.samples/xsd" name="m:header1" scope="default" expression="//sym:symbol"/>
```

Change your configuration which will be compatible with standards.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Header+Mediator